# IOS application does not render due to infinite while loop

Tags: ios, c, server

Hello I am implementing a primitive echo server for ios written purely in c. The issue arises when I enter an infinite while loop in order to accept incoming connections. Where is the best place to put the accept loop and is an infinite while loop (in my case all I want) the best implementation.

Here is the flow
Set root controller inside application function inside app delegate.
call start server function inside controller. (This function never returns)

```
while(true)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        int exchangeSocket = accept(socket, NULL,NULL);
        if(recv(exchangeSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"Error");
        }
        else
        {
            //do something with data received
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very unusual application. Certainly it is not a good idea to run an infinite loop in the main thread. You could try creating a separate thread for this.

Comment: Well examples in unix environments are usually implemented on a single thread so I am sure there could be a way to implement it on a single thread. I think my issue is more of where to place the loop in the context of the application's life cycle

Comment: I am writing up a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two concerns with your approach. First, you should not run an infinite loop on the main thread since that thread is already used for the main run loop. Blocking this loop with your own infinite loop (no matter where) will disrupt event processing. This is the answer to why your application does not render. The [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) specifies:

> Lengthy tasks (or potentially length tasks) should always be performed on a background thread. Any tasks involving network access, file access, or large amounts of data processing should all be performed asynchronously using GCD or operation objects

However, iOS does allow you to create threads using POSIX interfaces, e.g. it offers `pthread_create` and friends. You should be able to run your code in such  a thread without blocking your app.

Second, (but perhaps less of interest to you) using the POSIX networking APIs is somewhat [discouraged](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html) (due to failure of those APIs to turn on radio) in favor of other interfaces. What's closest to your liking may be [`CFSocket`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001445) (also a C interface).